# Way to make this sorting method work?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
list3 = []

elecStorage = []

elective = ["i", "j", "k", "l"]
prereq = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]

dict1 = {
1: SEM1period1, 2: SEM1period2,
3: SEM1period3, 4: SEM1period3,
5: SEM1period5, 6: SEM1period6,
7: SEM1period7, 8: SEM1period8
}

someNumber = 1


for key, dlist in dict1.items():
    if not dlist:
        list1.append("Free Period")
        someNumber += 1
        continue
    for item in dlist:
        if item in list1:
            continue
        elif item in elective:
            elecStorage.append(item)
        elif item in prereq:
            list1.append(item)
            someNumber += 1
            break
        if someNumber > len(list1):
            for index in elecStorage:
                if index in list1:
                    continue
                else:
                    list1.append(index)
                    someNumber += 1
            break
```

Note: Currently only SEM1period1, SEM1period2, and SEM1period3 contain anything. *SEM1period1* contains

```
["a", "c", e", "g"]
```

*SEM1period2* contains

```
["b", "d", "f", "h"]
```

and *SEM1period3* contains

```
["i", "j", "k", "l"]
```

When this code runs through it SHOULD save

```
["a", "b", "i", "Free Period", "Free Period", "Free Period", "Free Period", "Free Period"]
```

into *list1*. Instead it saves

```
["a", "b", "i", "j", "k", "l", "Free Period", "Free Period", "Free Period", "Free Period", "Free Period"]
```

Why is this? Is there a way I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your problem is a typo:

```
dict1 = {
1: SEM1period1, 2: SEM1period2,
3: SEM1period3, 4: SEM1period3,
                         #   ^
                         # should be 4!
```

also: while your code appears to run properly (as of Python 3.3.4), in general I would not trust the order of items in a dictionary! You are assuming that `dict1.items()` returns period 1, period 2, period 3... but in general a dictionary will return items in arbitrary (ie essentially random) order.

Comment: That was an issue isolated to my question, apologies. The issue persists.

Comment: (shrug) well, when I make that change and run it on the given data (with Python 3.3.4 32bit on Windows 7 Pro x64) I get `['a', 'b', 'i', 'Free Period', 'Free Period', 'Free Period', 'Free Period', 'Free Period']` which you have stated is your desired output.

Comment: Haha, whoops, you're right. I tried changing it around a bit afterwords. Thanks much, I'll apporve your answer. Sorry for the time waste.